# Removing Wordpress multisite

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to get my wordpress install back to a single site from multisite. I have followed exactly the steps pointed out in this link, but by the end of it my site just shows a blank screen with the site background and no other content. I can't even login to wp-admin.

http://www.poststat.us/completely-disable-multisite/

Please assist

Comment: Has the URL of the site changed?

Comment: Nope, the url is the same

Comment: Hmmm this is why I never use multisite. They're the devil. It's going to be really tough to answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion...

- Make a backup of the theme you want to use locally.
- Remove ALL themes except the default WP one TwentyTen, TwentyEleven, etc.
- Try the site again.
- If it comes back, re-upload your theme and activate it.

  - Working: Fantastic
  - Not working: Theres a problem with your theme.

Try that...

Comment: Its a problem with the theme..not sure why the theme is appearing blank, I can now log into the the admin and all the settings are there but cant seem to render the site

Comment: So this answers the question of the blank screen. Theres a separate question that needs to be asked about why the theme is giving errors. Mark this a answered and ask a separate question.